# Проверка репликации MySQL

Tags: mysql, репликация

Есть два хоста с репликацией (master-slave), которая в определенный момент была нарушена. Есть ли способы обнаружить разницу в состояниях двух БД (сразу скажу - я понимаю, что replication lag также сыграет свою роль в этой разнице), кроме построчного сравнения двух дампов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, такая возможность есть, для этого на слейв сервере следует выполнить команду

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS
```

В первую очередь нужно обратить внимание на столбцы `Slave_IO_Running` и `Slave_SQL_Running`, которые отражают состояние потоков доставки и выполнения бинлогов на реплику, соответственно. Если репликация выполняется штатно, оба они находятся в статусе Yes. Если один или оба из этих столбцов имеет статус No - репликация нарушена.

Для того, чтобы понять насколько реплика отстает от мастера, следует сравнивать текущие позиции в бинарных журналах на мастере и на слейв-сервере. На мастере для этого можно воспользоваться командой

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000003 | 73       | test         | manual,mysql     |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

Поле `File` вернет текущий файл бинарного журнала, поле `Position` - текущую позицию. Определить текущую позицию на слейв-сервере можно при помощи упомянутой выше команды

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
          Master_Host: localhost
          Master_User: root
          Master_Port: 3306
        Connect_Retry: 3
      Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
  Read_Master_Log_Pos: 73
       Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000003
        Relay_Log_Pos: 548
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
     Slave_IO_Running: Yes
    Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
      Replicate_Do_DB:
  Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Last_Errno: 0
           Last_Error:
         Skip_Counter: 0
  Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 73
      Relay_Log_Space: 552
      Until_Condition: None
       Until_Log_File:
        Until_Log_Pos: 0
   Master_SSL_Allowed: No
   Master_SSL_CA_File:
   Master_SSL_CA_Path:
      Master_SSL_Cert:
    Master_SSL_Cipher:
       Master_SSL_Key:
Seconds_Behind_Master: 8
```

Столбцы `Master_Log_File` и `Read_Master_Log_Pos` содержат имя бинарного журнала и позицию в нем на мастер-сервере, которые поток доставки бинлогов успел доставить на реплику. Бинарные логи ротируются, как правило, путем добавления расширение с номером лога, например

```
mysql-bin.000001
mysql-bin.000002
...
mysql-bin.000134
```

Таким образом, сравнив имя файла в полях `File` и `Master_Log_File`, а также позицию в файле `Position` и `Read_Master_Log_Pos` вы можете понять, насколько бинлоги слейва отстают от мастера. Следует иметь в виду, что эти поля описывают только доставку бинарных логов, их еще требуется выполнить. Поле `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` содержит позицию в бинарном логи, которую успел выполнить поток выполнения бинлогов. Если разница между `Read_Master_Log_Pos` и `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` велика, значит логи с мастера уже доставлены на реплику, однако слейв не успел их еще применить к данным.